# Tensorflow can't load libcudnn_cnn_infer.so.8?

Tags: windows, tensorflow, wsl-2

I Followed [the directions given by tensorflow for installation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) using wsl. Everything goes fine it looks like it recognized the gpu then I try to run a simple convolution neural net built in Keras and this is where things go wrong. The first thing I get  is when loading tensorflow is:

```
2023-04-14 16:49:19.416633: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
```

As I understand TensorRT is just an optimization and not necessary to run GPU acceleration on Tensorflow but I might be wrong.

the next message I get is

```
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2023-04-14 16:49:20.660159: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/numa_node
```

after this it does compile the network but once it starts training it errors out with the following

```
2023-04-14 16:49:23.948656: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:424] Loaded cuDNN version 8600
Could not load library libcudnn_cnn_infer.so.8. Error: libcuda.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Aborted
```

I tried this solution I found on another forum

```
/usr/lib/wsl/lib/libcuda.so.1 is not a symbolic link

Firstly,
    cd /usr/lib/wsl/lib/
backup "libcuda.so.1" and "libcuda.so",
and
    rm -r libcuda.so.1
    rm -r libcuda.so
Then,
    ln -s libcuda.so.1.1 libcuda.so.1
    ln -s libcuda.so.1.1 libcuda.so
    sudo ldconfig
done.
```

but this jus created a bunch of more errors.

Any help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66977227/could-not-load-dynamic-library-libcudnn-so-8-when-running-tensorflow-on-ubun Check this link

Comment: Could you please check the [step by step instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#step-by-step_instructions) given in the link and verify if you have followed all the steps and set the path of libraries correctly.  Also check the known issue in Ubuntu 22.04  and fix provided after Step 6 at the bottom of the same link. Let us know if the issue still persists.